# change color of RootViewController in UISplitView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

Like the question says.  I have a splitview with detail and root views.  How do I go about changing the color of the navigation bar in the root view?  Have tried:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59/256 green:115/256 blue:185/256 alpha:1.0];
```

in the root view `viewDidLoad:` method.  Clearly did not work, anyone know the proper way to do this?  I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myController.NavigationBar.TintColor` should do the trick.

Comment: Figured it out.  I didn't have my bar set to anything in IB.  Once I linked that up.  A slight variation did the trick: `self.rvBar.tintColor` where rvBar was a UINavigationBar.  Thanks for the solution Climber.  :D